# Using fixed device table instead of udev

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto

I'd like to generate a fixed device table in my embedded Linux image and skip using `udev`.

Following the *Yocto Dev Manual*, chapter* 5.18.1*, I've set the 2 variables `USE_DEVFS="0"` and `IMAGE_DEVICE_TABLES = "device_table-mymachine.txt"` and removed `udev` from the variable `VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_dev_manager`.

But the table was not created and I still need `udev` to populate devices.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Where do you get the Yocto Dev Manual? I do not see chapter 5.18.1

Comment: http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.0/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#selecting-dev-manager

Comment: Are you sure your `device_table-mymachine.txt` is valid? Can you add it?
Furthermore some logs of your systems boot process would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you have defined `device_table-mymachine.txt` but this is [device_table-minimal.txt](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-poky/blob/master/meta/files/device_table-minimal.txt) for example.

Secondly, without `udev`, you need to add another device manager such as BusyBox's `mdev` by specifying it in your conf/local.conf file as follow:

`VIRTUAL_RUNTIME_dev_manager = "mdev"`

Note that this will work only with core images that include `packagegroup-core-boot`

Comment: I have another question. I have 2 connections: 1 by ethernet using ssh/openssh and 1 by serial line. On the serial line, the login is assumed by sulogin through inittab. These 2 connections work well together. But since I replaced ssh/openssh by dropbear, I cannot login anymore on serial line. Does anyone has an idea? Thanks.